# Why parsing/unmarshalling xml file using JAXP behave differently on server?

Tags: java, xml

I have created a simple Java program that parses XML files and unmarshal the output into Java objects.

It works fine on my local machine(MacOS). But when I run the program on a server(Amazon Linux) with the same version(1.8.0_101) of Java as my local, it does not unmarshal XML fields at all(simply setting nullls).

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: You want us to debug a program we haven't seen, with the only known facts being that it produces different results in two environments which you haven't described in any detail? Get real.

Comment: Provided that my code is platform independent, where do you suggest to look into?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Techniques-Problem-Solving-Steven-Krantz/dp/082180619X/ref=sr_1_7?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1489516087&sr=1-7&keywords=problem+solving+techniques

Answer (score 0):

Creating a package-info.java in the package where all the JAXB generated classes reside.

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "https://sample.net/",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package ...;
import ...;
```